Use of ampersand (&) along with arrow operator (->) for inputting data into a struct in C, is it necessary?
My professor is currently teaching Binary Trees at college and she gave us a program to create a binary tree in C using Linked Lists.
However, there was a debate on whether ampersand (&) has to be used along with arrow operator (->) for inputting the node data into the tree's struct.
This is the snippet of the code that she gave us for creating a node:
BinTree *createNode() {
    BinTree* newnode;
    newnode = (BinTree*)malloc(sizeof(BinTree));
    printf("Enter data: ");
    scanf(" %c",newnode->data);
    newnode->lchild=NULL;
    newnode->rchild=NULL;
    return newnode;
}

However, when I run the entire finished code on my computer, the program terminates after giving the input.
1.Create
 2.Inorder
 3.preorder
 4.postorder
 5.exit
Enter your choice:1
 Enter data:A

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

However, when I add an ampersand & to the scanf, the code executes perfectly.
BinTree *createNode() {
    BinTree* newnode;
    newnode = (BinTree*)malloc(sizeof(BinTree));
    printf("Enter data: ");
    scanf(" %c",&newnode->data);
    newnode->lchild=NULL;
    newnode->rchild=NULL;
    return newnode;
}

I get the following output where the program doesn't terminate with an error code anymore.
1.Create
 2.Inorder
 3.preorder
 4.postorder
 5.exit
Enter your choice:1
 Enter data:A
 if you want left child press 1
1
Enter data:A
 if you want left child press 1

Which kind of confirms that the ampersand was quite important in this program. However, during Linked Lists, I have never used any ampersands while inserting data into the linked list nodes.
Why did I have to use an ampersand here then if the arrow operator -> is already pointing to the a struct member?

"during Linked Lists, I have never used any ampersands while inserting data into the linked list nodes." Can you show what code you used for inserting data into linked lists? It's quite difficult to see what your misunderstanding is.

You need to pass the address of the newnode.data, not the value of the data. To get the address of the data, we use the & operator.

The & operator has nothing to do with linked lists, but rather with scanf.

"if the arrow operator -> is already pointing to the a struct member?" Because the -> operator does not point to the struct member. newnode points to the struct and -> accesses the member within that struct.

You may want to stop thinking in terms of magic incantations and start thinking in terms of types. What type scanf(" %c", ___) requires in place of ___? What type does newnode->data have? What type does &newnode->data have?

@Sweeper I just went through my linked list codes from my previous semester and I noticed that I never directly inserted the data into the nodes using scanf but I did it by assigning the input value to the LL node directly in another statement

The ampersand & is necessary if you use scanf, because it provides the address of the variable. The arrow operator -> accesses the value directly, not its address, so & is needed to get the address of that member.

Then why isn't it compulsory with arrays? We can insert data into arrays without using the ampersand.

C18 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3) See also 2D Array seg fault (discussion of array-pointer conversion)

@SpaciousCoder78 Arrays are different from all other data types. :-) That is admitted as a mistake in the original C design, but they thought it was too late to change it when noticed.

Thanks, that clarifies it. I'm gonna share this with my professor.
